# Scrollview top and bottom

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I'm building and android application using android studio and I'm using scroll view in my layout, but the problem is that the scroll view doesn't start after the action bar and leaves huge white space at the bottom (as you can see in the screenshots below).

[image: the top of the scroll view]

[image: the bottom white space]

and here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:background="#fefcf8"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/info1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/info1" />
            </LinearLayout>
      .
      .
      .

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/info6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/info6" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:background="#3a3c3a"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see my xml above, i didn't any padding or margin. Yet there's a white space at the bottom and the scroll view starts at the very top of the activity not after the action bar. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting this inside your ScrollView or FrameLayout containing ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
...
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
...>
```

Comment: Then? Where can ii find the string?

Comment: It's one of the attribute set for every view class extending the layout. you just put these lines. If you want know more about this ...search !